# Polylines in google map V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi mates iam using poly lines in in my google map but iam facing some problem while using it.

```
flightPlanCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(30.265944, 78.0558291),new google.maps.LatLng(30.75, 76.78)];
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });

            flightPath.setMap(map);
```

This piece of code works perfectly but when i sightly change this code in this way it wont set line between two coordinates

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
flightPlanCoordinates[i] = [new google.maps.LatLng(msg.coordinates[i].latitude, msg.coordinates[i].longitude)];
}
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });

            flightPath.setMap(map);
```

Please help me.. thnks in advance

Comment: what are the values of msg.coordinates[]?  Perhaps you could provide a fiddl that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: 30.265944, 78.0558291 and 30.75, 76.78

Comment: How about a fiddle that exhibits the problem (or enough code to reproduce it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
flightPlanCoordinates[i] = [new google.maps.LatLng(msg.coordinates[i].latitude, msg.coordinates[i].longitude)];
}
```

Just change your this one code from the code given below

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
flightPlanCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(msg.coordinates[i].latitude, msg.coordinates[i].longitude);
}
```

And let me whether it works or not